# In ArcGIS Pro, why does a feature appear on an exported layout even though I deleted it from its layer?

Tags: layout, export, arcgis

For some reason, I have a feature that appears on an exported layout even though I deleted the feature from it's layer. The feature does is not visible when the layer is shown in the map pane, nor the layout pane. When I export the layer, it is still there.

I save the project, close Arc GIS Pro, and then open it, and the feature is back on the layer. This seems like a bug to me. Has anyone experienced this before?

I am using ArcGIS 3.1.1

Comment: Does anybody have an idea of why this would be?